Pandas create complex rolling calculation in groupby
I have a dataset in Pandas consisting of phone call logs, from several caller numbers into several destination numbers. Calls are logged as soon as they are completed.
Main features:

unix_timestamp (index)
caller_number
dest_number (US Toll Free)
real_duration

Sample df



unix_ts
caller_number
dest_number
real_duration




1674567050.6435
16175962600.0
18448213248
435.0


1680545624.27747
14103914538.0
18775057141
497.0


1681923808.21773
19182890899.0
18006485010
132.0


1684535428.48401
15202197200.0
18883507446
450.0


1697056646.38694
13236327145.0
18888544812
390.0



I need to identify those destiantion numbers that have limited the call duration. Especially those where at least the last five calls have the same duration (flat line).
The pseudo code to identify the flat line condition is as follows:

Split stage: groupby dest_number, without calculations
Apply stage: for each individual frame after the split, add 5 new columns with shifted values of real_duration, calculate the mean and the std of the last 5 calls real_duration, column wise. Then add a column with the ratio_pre = std / mean.
Combine stage: output is a df with index dest_number and one column with the last_ratio_pre for each frame

After these transformations, the resulting dataframe should look like this:



dest_number
real_duration_sum
last_ratio_pre




18008259452
107278.0
2.1310975127055425


18773310081
94171.0
0.001336663795067271


18885436765
56977.0
0.03930810818390873


18009423141
40031.0
0.14554363343695811


18886450451
22803.0
0.9798228336647965



After extensive research, the code with which I implemented the solution is as follows:

# create a pandas groupby class, without applying any calculation
df_dest_temp = df.groupby(['dest_number'], sort=True)

# add column last_ratio_pre and fill it with ones as placeholders
df_dest['last_ratio_pre'] = 1

# define how many previous values
control = 5

# iterate over groupby components, and assign to df_dest one by one *** SUPER SLOW!! ***
for num, frame in df_dest_temp:
    
    # create a temp df
    df_temp = frame[['dest_number', 'real_duration']]
    
    # create 5 new columns that hold the shifted values of real_duration
    for i in range(control):
        df_temp['pre_'+str(i+1)] = df_temp.real_duration.shift(i+1)

    # select only the columns related to real_duration
    cols = ['real_duration'] + [col for col in df_temp.columns if col.startswith('pre_')]

    # calculate mean of last 5 real_durations, by columns
    mean_pre  = df_temp[cols].mean(axis=1)
    
    # calculate std of last 5 real_durations, by columns
    std_pre = df_temp[cols].std(axis=1)

    # assign results to new columns
    df_temp['mean_pre'] = mean_pre
    df_temp['std_pre']  = std_pre
    
    # calculate the ratio between std and mean
    df_temp['ratio_pre']  = std_pre / mean_pre

    # take each fram and groupby dest_number and choose last value for ratio_pre
    df_temp_grouped = df_temp.groupby('dest_number').ratio_pre.last()

    # assign result to df_dest
    df_dest.loc[num, 'ratio_pre'] = float(df_temp_grouped.values)


As it can be seen, the code above solves the problem but in a VERY slow way. I did not find a way to include all the functionality in a lambda function, or in a vectorized way.
I will certainly welcome comments, remarks and suggestions to make the code more efficient.

Would this work?
import pandas as pd

# sample data
data = {
    "unix_ts": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    "dest_number": [111, 111, 222, 222, 333, 333],
    "real_duration": [100, 100, 10, 20, 1000, 0],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# sort (most recent first)
df = df.sort_values(by="unix_ts", ascending=False)

# calculate ratio of mean to std of real_duration for the last 5 calls for each dest_number
def func(df):
    df = df.iloc[:5]  # last 5 calls
    ratio = df["real_duration"].mean() / df["real_duration"].std()
    return ratio


df.groupby("dest_number").apply(func)



It works like a charm. Nothing beats simplicity and elegance. Thanks a lot! I was definitly blinded by the trees, did not see the forest.
